# OPENJSON - modify statement to ignore first part of the string

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2017

We receive auto-generated emails from an application, and we export those to our database as they arrive at the Inbox.  The table is called `dbo.MailArchive`.

Up until recently, the body of the email has always looked like this...

```
Status: Completed
Successful actions count: 250
Page load count: 250
```

...except with different numbers and statuses. **Note that there is a carriage return on the blank line after Page load count.**

The entirety of this data gets written to a field called `Mail_Body` - then we run the following statement using `OPENJSON` to parse those lines into their own columns in the record:

```sql
DECLARE @PI varchar(7) = '%[^' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ']%';

SELECT j.Status,
       j.Successful_Actions_Count,
       j.Page_Load_Count
FROM dbo.MailArchive m
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REVERSE(m.Mail_Body),PATINDEX(@PI,REVERSE(m.Mail_Body)))) PI(SY,I)
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(REVERSE(STUFF(PI.SY,1,PI.I,''))))S(FixedString)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (CONCAT('{"', REPLACE(REPLACE(S.FixedString, ': ', '":"'), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '","'), '"}')) 
                 WITH (Status varchar(100) '$.Status',
                       Successful_Actions_Count int '$."Successful actions count"',
                       Page_Load_Count int '$."Page load count"') j;
```

Beginning today, there are certain emails where the body of the email looks like this:

```
Agent did not meet defined success criteria on this run.

Status: Completed
Successful actions count: 250
Page load count: 250
```

To clarify, that's one new line at the top, a carriage return at the end of that line, and a carriage return on the blank line between the new line and the `Status` line. At this time, there is no consistent way to predict which emails will come in with this new line, and which ones won't.

How can I modify our `OPENJSON` statement to say, If this first line exists in the body, skip/ignore it and parse lines 3 through 5, else just do exactly what I have above?  Or perhaps even better to future-proof it, always ignore everything before the word `Status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data has new leading and trailing rows, I think a simple aggregation in concert with a `string_split()` and a `CROSS APPLY` would be more effective than my previous XML answer and the current JSON approach

**Example [or dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f13e9534cc4271f46fceb3f27d10017a)**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Status  = stuff(Pos1,1,charindex(':',Pos1),'')
      ,Action  = try_convert(int,stuff(Pos2,1,charindex(':',Pos2),''))
      ,PageCnt = try_convert(int,stuff(Pos3,1,charindex(':',Pos3),''))
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
               Select [Pos1] = max(case when Value like 'Status:%' then value end)
                     ,[Pos2] = max(case when Value like '%actions count:%' then value end)
                     ,[Pos3] = max(case when Value like 'Page load count:%' then value end)
                From  string_split(SomeCol,char(10))
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID   Status     Action  PageCnt
1    Completed  250     250
```

**Note: Use an `OUTER APPLY` if you want to see NULLs**